# User Tablet as Touch Monitor For Windows 10

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, touchscreen, extended-desktop

How can i extend my desktop (extended monitors without actual monitors) onto a couple of tablets in order to use them as Touch Screens. (Example a program with buttons onscreen) 
Ive tried the following, 
iDisplay (the client / phone app will not launch on any of my devices )
Splashtop (slow performance. touch input is relative not point to point. And only duplicates existing monitor)
AirScreen, Spacedesk and non of them work the way i need them to.

I haven't been able to fake a monitor and use remote desktop apps either.

Comment: @seth all cleaned up

Comment: Much better. Which way did they work that they didn't satisfy your requirements? What kind of tablets do you have? What does your working scenario look like?

Comment: @Seth I Will add more information to the question